# Url Rewriting using asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

am getting this error after rewriting the url as follows in web.config file

```
<location path="Speakers.aspx">
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="localhost/Speakers" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
    </httpRedirect>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like rewriting to me. That just looks like you're redirecting all traffic to localhost/Speakers. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to remove extension from url thats why used this... extension is removed but page doesnot show

Answer (score 1):

You can use rewrite rules in `<system.webServer>` like:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>        
        <rule name="MyPage" enabled="true">
            <match url="^MyPage/$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyPage.html" />
        </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The above example would show the content of the MyPage.html page when the user had the URL /MyPage/

Comment: i have tried this. it shows me internal server error on the host

Comment: Where in your web.config did you put it? Can you see the actual error? Also, maybe show me the exact code you put in, in case there's an issue with that. It is also possible to add wildcards or use regex to do matches etc.

Comment: at the start inside <configuration>

Comment: You need to put it inside <system.webServer> as I mentioned above :)

Comment: i did as it is but it shows me as: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
   <rules>        
        <rule name="Speakers" enabled="true">
            <match url="^Speakers/$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/Speakers.aspx" />
        </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
 </system.webServer>

Comment: So you're getting a 404 when you go to /Speakers/ or are you putting /Speakers the trailing slash is included in the example you give.

Comment: What is the URL that link goes to?

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: Can you copy and paste the URL in the address bar that you are on when you get the 404 error.

Comment: you have any other option to remove the extensions in url

Comment: No, the above should work however it should be with a / on the end in the example I give.

Comment: i tried without / as well its not working. There is .aspx in the end